# Interesting variation of the TNSPING Message 3511 error

Tags: oracle11g

I have the following problem with Oracle 11g TNSPING utility: fresh 11g client installation, ORACLE_HOME set up properly, TNS_ADMIN also set, msb files available in desired location, readable by the user that invokes TNSPING. Connection to the database works, sqlplus can be used to connect. TNSPING, however, fails badly. See attached log:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\USERNAME>set ORACLE_HOME=C:\Work\Software\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1

C:\Users\USERNAME>set TNS_ADMIN=%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin

C:\Users\USERNAME>set NLS_LANG=ENGLISH_POLAND.EE8MSWIN1250

C:\Users\USERNAME>dir %TNS_ADMIN%\tnsnames.ora
 Volume in drive C is XXX
 Volume Serial Number is YYY

 Directory of C:\Work\Software\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin

2013-03-19  12:26               358 tnsnames.ora
               1 File(s)            358 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  59 082 616 832 bytes free

C:\Users\USERNAME>dir %ORACLE_HOME%\network\mesg\tns*.msb
 Volume in drive C is XXX
 Volume Serial Number is YYY

 Directory of C:\Work\Software\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\mesg

2010-03-31  07:01            53 248 tnspl.msb
2010-03-31  07:01            47 104 tnsus.msb
               2 File(s)        100 352 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  59 082 616 832 bytes free

C:\Users\USERNAME>sqlplus <USER>/<PASSWORD>@<DATABASE>

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Tue Mar 19 14:36:34 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

C:\Users\USERNAME>tnsping <DATABASE>

TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 19-MAR-2013 14:37:52

Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Message 3511 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNSMessage 3512 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNSMessage 3513 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNSMessage 3509 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNS
```

Please note: I had to replace all the user credentials, database name, etc., due to security considerations.

Can you help me, please, troubleshoot the issue? I have read all the other StackExchange topics related to TNSPING failure, but each of the solutions (set up ORACLE_HOME, reinstall, make sure registry points to proper home, check msb files) has failed me...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: any solution helped you?